# Reading a very simple ajax request in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I lately managed to get a simple ajax post to work but can't get any of the data in the controller :

Ajax :

```
function verify(event) {
        var title = event.title;
        var start = event.start.format("h:m");
        $.ajax({
            url: "/admin/timetable/verify",
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('#crsf').val()
            },
            type: "post",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: {type : 'hi',titles : title},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response){
                if (response['state']==='0')
                    toastr.error('Are you the 6 fingered man?'+response['msg']);

                if (response['state']==='1')
                    toastr.info('Are you the 6 fingered man?');
            },
            error : function(e){
                console.log(e.responseText);
            }

        });

    }
```

Controller :

```
 $d = Request::all();
        dd($d);
        return response()->json(['state'=>'0','msg'=>$d['titles']],200);
```

I tried Request all, Input all, Input::json()->all() .. nothing works always null or empty array [] ! I'm just trying to read the data sent from the ajax form !

Comment: what is ``d`` and ``dd``?

Comment: d is a variable holding request data if any, and dd is the debuger of laravel :)

Comment: Could you please add a dollar sign to ``d``, it looks kinda confusing ;)

Comment: You are aborting the action with dd, so you won't get data back.

Comment: Please READ the question. I'm trying to see if ANY data is transmitted, and dd is not SHOWING as it is a DEBUGGER any data. The response has nothing to do here !

Comment: Also, inject request in your controller, then read it with $request->title.

Comment: Where do you think dd will output something? It's an Ajax request

Comment: It is outputting in the browser console

Comment: Guys you really missing the point here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this lately. The problem (I don't know why) was about Get and POST.

Just transform route to a GET, make the ajax type as GET, and try with a very simple `Input::all`.

```
 public function verifyClassroom(){
        $Data = Input::all();
        dd($Data);
}
```

Comment: This is just insane .. it worked but can't get why a GET would work and not the POST !

Comment: Well to be honest, me neither.

Answer (score 1):

This is my tested code and it works

```
function verify(event) {              
    $.ajax({
        url: "/test",
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('#crsf').val()
        },
        type: "post",
        data: {type : 'hi',titles : "title"},
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        },
        error : function(e){
            console.log(e.responseText);
        }
});
```

}

and in my route closure

```
Route::post('test', function(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request){

    $type   = ($request->input('type'));
    return $type;//returns type->hi
});
```

Comment: As said, already tried this. And what is changed in the ajax ?

Comment: try removing `dataType` and `contentType` and do `$request->all()` not `Request::all()`

Comment: when removing the contentType and dataType it only pushes to do an additional test in controller but keeps the data empty.

Comment: I did that, no chance. Chaibi Alaa, don't know what test, but without those two I have an empty array when trying $request->all().

Answer (score 0):

in the php controller you need to have something like this.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class YourcontrollernameController extends Controller {

 public function test(Request $request) {

  echo $request->input('type');
  echo '/';
  echo $request->input('titles');
  die;
 }
}
```

you can access the `type` and `title` by `$request->input('type')` and `$request->input('titles')`

ALso try using get method and 
in `yourproject/routes/web.phpweb.php`

```
Route::get('/test', 'YourcontrollernameController@test');
```